# How can I link a new window to the main window?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

This is my Main Method.

```
package GUI_MOCKUPS;

public class MainMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MainMenu() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    // GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("LookBook");
        setIconImages(null);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Ece Miclat\\Downloads\\imageedit_16_6973734870.png")); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Ece Miclat\\Downloads\\imageedit_7_6594918757.png")); // NOI18N

        jTextField1.setText("Search");
        jTextField1.setToolTipText("");
        jTextField1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 12));
        jButton1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 204));
        jButton1.setText("Home");
        jButton1.setBorder(null);
        jButton1.setBorderPainted(false);
        jButton1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Books");
        jButton2.setBorder(null);
        jButton2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Authors");
        jButton3.setBorder(null);
        jButton3.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Borrower's Slip");
        jButton4.setBorder(null);
        jButton4.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField2.setEditable(false);
        jTextField2.setText("|");
        jTextField2.setBorder(null);

        jTextField3.setEditable(false);
        jTextField3.setText("|");
        jTextField3.setBorder(null);

        jTextField4.setEditable(false);
        jTextField4.setText("|");
        jTextField4.setBorder(null);

        jTextField5.setEditable(false);
        jTextField5.setText("Enter Book Title, Author, Subject or Category");
        jTextField5.setToolTipText("");
        jTextField5.setBorder(null);

        jButton5.setText("Submit");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(51, 51, 51).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 254, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 157, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addGap(18, 18, 18).addComponent(jButton5))).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(jLabel2).addGap(48, 48, 48)).addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap(114, Short.MAX_VALUE).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING).addComponent(jLabel1).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(jButton1).addGap(18, 18, 18).addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addGap(18, 18, 18).addComponent(jButton2).addGap(18, 18, 18).addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addGap(18, 18, 18).addComponent(jButton3).addGap(18, 18, 18).addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addGap(18, 18, 18).addComponent(jButton4).addGap(21, 21, 21))).addGap(112, 112, 112)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(36, 36, 36).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(jButton1).addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addComponent(jButton2).addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addComponent(jButton3).addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addComponent(jButton4)).addGap(38, 38, 38).addComponent(jLabel1).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING).addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup().addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addComponent(jLabel2)).addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(38, 38, 38).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addComponent(jButton5)).addGap(38, 38, 38).addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))).addGap(22, 22, 22)));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>
     // GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { }

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { }

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { }

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { }

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainMenu().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

While this one is the one I want to link to it.

```
package GUI_MOCKUPS;

public class BorrowSlipServer extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BorrowSlipServer() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    // GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("LookBook");
        setIconImages(null);

        jTextField1.setEditable(false);
        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 24));
        jTextField1.setText("Reserve Book");
        jTextField1.setBorder(null);
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField3.setEditable(false);
        jTextField3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 14));
        jTextField3.setText(" Book Reserved:");
        jTextField3.setBorder(null);

        jTextField2.setEditable(false);
        jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 14));
        jTextField2.setText(" Reserved By:");
        jTextField2.setBorder(null);
        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField4.setEditable(false);
        jTextField4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 14));
        jTextField4.setText(" Student No.");
        jTextField4.setBorder(null);

        jTextField5.setEditable(false);
        jTextField5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 14));
        jTextField5.setText(" Book No.");
        jTextField5.setBorder(null);
        jTextField5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText(" Submit");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap(38, Short.MAX_VALUE).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(88, 88, 88).addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)).addGap(34, 34, 34).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)).addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup().addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 249, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addComponent(jButton1))).addGap(40, 40, 40)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(59, 59, 59).addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addGap(25, 25, 25).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)).addGap(28, 28, 28).addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)).addGap(30, 30, 30).addComponent(jButton1).addContainerGap(61, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>
     // GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { }

    private void jTextField5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { }

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new BorrowSlipServer().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _link_?

Comment: Probably to pass the objects to each other, in the `A a = new A(); B b = new B(); a.setB(b);b.setA(a);` style, so that methods in one instance can access methods of the other.

Comment: What will you achieve, since everything is `private` in both the classes except for the `Constructor` part ? Please do elaborate your needs/problem :-) Just for heads up, try to write `BorrowSlipServer.main("nothing to pass")` somewhere in your `MainMenu` class, you will get one idea, though this isn't a good programming practice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe through one of your button clicks or constructor you can pass:

```
new BorrowSlipServer().setVisible(true);
```

while also adding some parameters to BorrowSlipServer(String s1,String s2) to pass whatever you want to pass from your main to it.

It's still not clear what you mean by "link",do you want to pass things from your MainMenu to BorrowSlipServer or do the opposite?

On a side note you may wanna add:

```
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

This will center your window on run but make sure you add it after you set the frame size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//add this button to the panel/frame of choice
JButton newLink= new JButton("New JFrame");
newFrame.addActionListener(new frameListener());

//put this listener class in file(s) you want to navigate in-between
private class frameListener() implements ActionListener
{
   public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
        new NextJFrame();
   }
}
```